# how to count visits on a period of time php

Tags: php, sql

How can I count the number of visits on a page for A PERIOD OF TIME in php and sql

right now what I have is a field called number of visits for every page. but it is just a number it does not tell you the time of the visits. I do not mind opening a new column just for counting the visits for a certain month. but how can I do that?

why I am doing that? just for a monthly report showing me which website pages improved more than the other. 
Ideas? codes?

everything is welcomed

Comment: Sure. They call it Google Analytics.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Amen to that, if the system is still in this stage of infancy it's better to go for the guys that know their stuff ;-)

Comment: If you did want to manually track it, you would need to track every page request's path and timestamp in a table. Then you can select the rows that exist between dates using MySQL's DATE/TIME functions. But that would need to be purged periodically, since it can grow pretty large.

Comment: There's also [Piwik](http://piwik.org/), if you're not into Google snooping your site visitors. A word of caution, though: Any script you use from the web could be a potential threat to your server and surreptitiously steal your site's information. So be careful what you use. There's a plethora of "clone" scripts out there.

Comment: +1 @JaredFarrish - There is also web.analytics.yahoo.com/

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to make something called "popular pages of the month!" It is gonna be very complicated If I wanted to take something from google analytics and display it on my site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just for quick tracking, you could include a counter script to each page. Here's a very crude illustration in PHP:

```
<?php
    $datafile = 'pick_a_filename.txt';
    if(file_exists($datafile)) {
        $count = file_get_contents($datafile);
        $count++;
        $fp = fopen($datafile, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $count);
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        $count = 1;
        $fp = fopen($datafile, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $count);
        fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```

And then just check the created file every month, or add a script that appends the contents to a statistic file every month. If there's lots of traffic, include a LOCK_EX and a random delay before writing so the count does not reset when two people write it at the same time - that has happened to me even on a small site when I used just a LOCK_EX! The random delay fixed it.